# Modal - pop up shows when a value in a dropdown change. AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, popup

Here is my code for a dropdown in my project:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label for="status">{{ 'SERVICE_STATUS' | translate }}</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="status" ng-model="ctrl.service.status" ng-options="status_id as status_name for (status_id, status_name) in ctrl.statusChoices" ng-model="showModal"></select> 
</div>
```

When the value of this dropdown changes (by a selection from the user) it shows a pop up to validate the change (something like "Are you sure that you want to do this?" and a click with a "OK").

Here is the code of the modal-pop up:

```
<div class="modal-dialog {{size ? 'modal-' + size : ''}}" ng-show="showModal">
<div class="modal-content" uib-modal-transclude>
<div class="modal-header" ng-controller="ContentHeaderController as chctrl">
    <div class="pages-header">
        <h3>{{ 'SERVICE_STATUS' | translate}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>{{ 'SERVICE_STATUS_CHANGE' | translate }}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="flex-end">
        <button type="button" class="page-button"
                ng-click="chctrl.close()">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>{{ 'SERVICE_STATUS_CONFIRM' | translate }}</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note: this two html codes are in the same html file.

I tried to do this using the ng-model and ng-show directives but it seems not to be working because it doesn't do anything when I select a value in the dropdown.
Any idea about how to implement this or what can I use?

Comment: Have you read the instructions here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal ?

Comment: Are you sure you can toggle a $uibModal like that?